# How to bring label tag in the first row of textarea?

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3, css-float, alignment

I am having 3 row textarea tag. But my label tag is present in the 3rd row of the text area. But I wanted it in the first row. How to do it. Please help me and let me why it is in the last row ?

The problem follows here.[image]

My code is in the following.

http://jsbin.com/zisem/2/edit

Comment: what text is your legend again?

Comment: legend tag can you please explain in code there no legend tag?

Comment: @rockStar : That was big typo mistake. That was label tag.

Comment: @Harish : My mistake. It was lebel tag. And also I wanted the labels should be in the left side well aligned and the values should be in the right side with well aligned. How to do it with google maps info window object.

Comment: ok you can achieve with @matewka answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following style to your label

```css
label {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Only by adding some `width` Form will look more nice.